# Interpreting description of hierarchical agglomerative clustering application

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to replicate a clustering methodology described in a paper as

> We define the hetereogeneity metric within a cluster to be the average
> of all-pair jaccard distances, and at each step merge two clusters if
> the heterogeneity of the resultant cluster is below a specified
> threshold

There is a footnote `we set the threshold to zero`

I'm using `scipy`, my question isn't about scipy but I'll describe the steps I've taken using that API.

1. I start with an array of input examples `x`
2. I create a distance matrix `y` where `y[i,j] = jaccard(x[i],x[j])`
3. I compute the linkage `z=linkage(y, method='average')`
4. I compute the clusters `fcluster(z, t=0.0, criterion='distance')`

What I'm uncertain about is the authors description that clusters are merged when `the heterogeneity of the resultant cluster is below a specified threshold (which was zero)`

I understand t is the threshold that represents the `cophenetic distance`. Am I correct in assuming that if a cluster contains two identical points (i.e. the jackard distance is zero) and no other points then the heterogeneity is zero and hence using a threshold (cophenetic distance) of zero should identify all clusters that only contain points having a jaccard distance between them of zero?

Or is there a different way to automatically extract clusters where `heterogeneity==0`?

The main reason for my confusion is the author's conclusion that the accuracy of their method is around 90% but I find setting t=0 always returns singleton clusters. Furthermore it's quite hard to find a t which works well in all cases.